# node js restify calling method from another file

Tags: node.js, restify

I am simply trying to call a function from another file, but I am getting an error when starting the node server...

Here is my server.js:

```
var restify = require('restify');

/* Declare object files */
var theProperties = require('./properties');

var server = restify.createServer({ 
    name: 'AptTin-API' 
});

server.get('/:name', theProperties.runningProp);

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

And I am trying to call this function from properties.js which is in the same directory:

```
function runningProp(req, res, next) {
  res.send('hello properties ' + req.params.name);
  next();
}
```

These seems straightforward enough, but it does not work...

Answer (score 2):

In properties.js you need to export your function. Like so:

```
exports.runningProp = function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('hello properties ' + req.params.name);
  next();
}
```